# EF Tracing Provider determining calling method, or entity being queried

Tags: linq, entity-framework, logging, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I've gotten the EFTracingProvider to work with my code first application, but when logging, my application tries to log the calling class.  Since my context is always where the EFTracing Provider resides, that is what's getting stored in the calling class, even though the actual attempt to reference the entity happened in another class.

Is there anyway to either track where the actual call happened, or to track which entity or DBSet in the context was trying to be accessed, which then caused the Tracing to fire?